# Scale centered image with jquery

Tags: jquery, show

I have a centered image and I want to scale it with jquery. 
The problem is that it scales first and positioned on a 
second step.

```
.outer {
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   background: #f5f5f5;
   text-align: center;
}
#inner {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omudeaxd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `animate()` instead of `show()`:

Just replace your `js` with this:

```
$( document ).ready (function () {
    $('#inner').css({'height':0,'width':0})
    $('#inner').animate({height:300+"px",width:300+"px"},1900)
});
```

[check in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omudeaxd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use keyframes for this? Looks nice, and is hardware accelerated!

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/omudeaxd/2/

```
#inner {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    animation: zoom 1900ms;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
  100% {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
  }
}
```